# VS2019 popen not using environment variables

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to make a sort of `eval` command in my VS project and I've come across an error. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using string = std::string;

string eval(string cmd) {
    std::ofstream ree;
    ree.open("WRITEFILE.cpp", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
    ree << cmd;
    ree.close();
    char buffer[128];
   string result = "";
   const char* cmdstr = "g++ WRITEFILE.cpp -o WRITE.exe && WRITE.exe"; // + libraries once I get it working
   std::cout << cmdstr;
   FILE* pipe = _popen(cmdstr, "r");
   if (!pipe) {
      return "popen failed!";
   }
  while (!feof(pipe)) {

  // use buffer to read and add to result
  if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
     result += buffer;
   }

   _pclose(pipe);
   return result;
}
```

My `Path` Environment variable includes my mingw bin directory as well as the folder that I store all my libraries in; however I get the error `'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command.'` Furthermore, if I substitute `g++` with the full path, it doesn't find the libraries in the same folder. I know it isn't an environment variable issue, as I use G++ for all my smaller projects (this one doesn't work with it) and have had no issues. I'm not sure where to go now so any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you recently change the PATH environment variable? I ask because environment variables are inherited from the owning process.

Comment: You can inspect the PATH environment variable by clicking properties on your project then Debugging -> Environment then Edit and type $(Path) in the top window of the popup. Visual Studio 2019 will show the value of the PATH environment being sent to application when it will be debugged in the Visual Studio Community / Enterprise or Pro.

Comment: oh... i completely forgot that I changed that! Seems that was the issue... sorry about that. Thanks so much!

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, I would appreciate it if you could write them as answer and mark them. Because this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can inspect the PATH environment variable by clicking properties
> on your project then Debugging -> Environment then Edit and type
> $(Path) in the top window of the popup. Visual Studio 2019 will show
> the value of the PATH environment being sent to application when it
> will be debugged in the Visual Studio Community / Enterprise or Pro.
> Thanks to @dresherjm